# "Look into" vs. "look at" in the 'investigate, explore' sense

Tags: word-choice, differences, verbs, prepositions

Are *look into* and *look at* interchangeable? If not what are the differences between the two?

> I will **look at** my options and see what I have.
>
> I will **look into** my options and see what I have.
>
> I will **look into** it and let you know. Or the government is going to **look into** the case.

Answer (score 13):

*Look at* suggests that you already know what your options are and will review them, whereas *look into* suggests that you first need to investigate what those options might be.

Answer (score 4):

In the above mentioned context,

> **Look into something:** investigate, to inquire into

- Look into a question.
- The governor asked the police commissioner to look into the case.

> **Look at something:** examine

- We must look at the question from all sides.
- Doctor, will you please look at my ankle?
- Will you please look at the battery of my car?

Usually, "look at" and "look into" are interchangeable. In such cases (of interchangeability) *"look into something"* suggests a more thorough examination (of something) than *"look at something"*.

In the sentences you have provided, "look at" and "look into" can be interchanged.